# ¿Cómo eliminar tareas específicas en Celery?

Tags: django, celery

Estoy usando Celery en mi app de Django con Docker para crear tareas que se ejecuten en determinadas situaciones. Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de acceder a la cola o tabla donde se almacenan las tareas de Celery y eliminar alguna en específico.

Pregunto porque tengo esta situación: tengo un signal para que cuando se inserte o modifique un objeto de tipo Ocurrencia (por ejemplo), se mande a ejecutar un task. Sin embargo no todas las modificaciones en Ocurrencia necesitan ejecutar el task, solo cuando se modifiquen ciertos campos.

```
signals.py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Ocurrencia)
def comprobar_ocurrencia(sender, instance, created, update_fields, *args, **kwargs):
    # compruebo si se inserta por primera vez
    if created:
        # hago algunas cosillas y mando a ejecutar el task
        notificar_actividad.apply_async(args=[...], eta=instance.fecha)
    elif created == False:
        if 'contenido_alarma' in update_fields:
            # si solo se modificó el campo contenido_alarma, por ejemplo
            # borrar cualquier task relacionado con la ocurrencia que estoy manejando
            # para insertar un nuevo task
                notificar_actividad.apply_async(args=[...], eta=instance.fecha)

tasks.py
@app.task
def notificar_actividad(*args):
    # el codigo que se ejecuta en el task
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se modifique Ocurrencia, primer comprobar que solamente se modificaron ciertos campos y luego eliminar cualquier task asociado con esa ocurrencia y poner uno nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar esto:

```
$ celery -A proyecto purge
```

también esto:

```
from proj.celery import app
app.control.purge()
```

o esto desde el mismo django shell:

1. Ingresas a tu entorno virtual
2. Entras a tu proyecto
3. Shell django `manage.py celery purge`

Comment: El comando purge elimina todos los tasks? Si es asi entonces no me sirve, yo necesito eliminar uno o varios tasks en especifico

Comment: Tú pregunta es "Cómo eliminar tareas en celery". Tasks = notificar_actividad.

Comment: Te entiendo, agregué la palabra "específicas" al título para evitar confusiones.

Answer (score 1):

`apply_async` devuelve el `id` en la respuesta dentro de un [AsyncResult](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult)

Con este `id` podrías utilizar `revoke` para notificar a *Celery* que cuando le toque ejecutar esta tarea, no lo haga.

```
from celery.task.control import revoke

revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Comment: En mi caso yo uso apply_async, como podria obtener el id del task?

Comment: Perdon, quería decir `apply_async` :-P